# Related objects as separate endpoint (the "edge" model) using Django Rest Framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

**Update**: it looks like this problem has been solved by some third-party packages ([drf-nested-routers](https://github.com/alanjds/drf-nested-routers) and [drf-extensions](http://chibisov.github.io/drf-extensions/docs/#nested-routes)).  Is there no easy way to do this with vanilla DRF?

## Background

I'm trying to figure out how to build an API where endpoints can have additional "edges" that can be used to look up related objects, rather than including those related objects (or their pks) in the endpoint of the "master" object itself.  This can be handy when there are a *lot* of related objects, since including the related objects in the response for the master object would be expensive.

Some examples of this style of API are the GitHub API and the Facebook Graph API:

[`/repos/:owner/:repo/issues`](https://developer.github.com/v3/issues/#list-issues-for-a-repository) => gets a list of *issues* related to the *repo*

[`/v2.9/{photo-id}/likes`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/photo/likes/) => gets a list of *likes* related to the *photo*

## Example

In the contrived example below I would have thought that a `list_route` in the `ViewSet` could be used to build this sort of relationship, but instead it creates a url of the form `/repos/issues/` instead of `/repos/{pk}/issues/`.  If I change it to `detail_route` it leaves the `{pk}` in the URL, but that seems like an abuse of `detail_route` since that's really meant to return a single object, right?

```
class Repo(models.Model):
    name = models.TextField()


class Issue(models.Model):
    title = models.TextField()
    body = models.TextField()
    repo = models.ForeignKey(Repo)


class RepoSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Repo
        fields = ('pk', 'name')
        # don't want to include all issues here, there might be a lot.


class IssueSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Issue
        fields = ('pk', 'title', 'body')


class RepoViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = RepoSerializer

    # THIS DOESN'T WORK!  It creates:
    # /repos/issues/ rather than /repos/{pk}/issues/
    @list_route(serializer_class=IssueSerializer)
    def issues(self):
        repo = self.get_object()
        issues = repo.issue_set.all()
        s = self.get_serializer(issues, many=True)
        return Response(s.data)


router.register(r'repos', RepoViewSet, base_name='repos')
```

Any ideas how I can get a `/repos/{pk}/issues/` URL out of this guy?

Comment: No reason `detail_route` should only return a single instance, detail route is a route on one instance (detail view) but may return a list relative to that instance. Look at the second example: http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/routers/#example where `detail_route` decorator is used.

Comment: Interesting, didn't realize that. Feel free to submit as an answer and I'll accept!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no reason `detail_route` should only return a single instance, `detail_route` is a route on one instance (detail view) but may return a list relative to that instance.

Look at the second example of [DRF docs](http://django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/routers/#example): `detail_route` decorator is used to return a list.